# How to send an HTTP request from AWS Lambda function to on-prem server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to send an http request from my Lambda function to an on-prem server.

Regarding network configurations:
I've associated the Lambda function with a VPC that already has a functioning site-to-site connection, and have associated it to a private subnet within this VPC.

VPC's route table has a route with the IP CIDR of the on-prem server (with a /24 mask) that points to the VGW of the site-to-site connection.

Private subnet's route table also has a route with the IP CIDR of the on-prem server (with a /24 mask) that points to the VGW of the site-to-site connection.

I'm still getting timed out.
What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried setting up a private NAT gateway and associating it with the private subnet. I've tried having it as the target in the route table for the IP CIDR of the on-prem server.

Comment: If you launch an EC2 instance into the same VPC+subnet and with the same SG as the Lambda function, can it reach the on-prem endpoint?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work! Turns out you need 2 subnets for this to work.

- Associate the Lambda function with subnet A.
- Create a private NAT gateway and attach it to subnet B.
- In subnet A, create a route for the IP CIDR of the on-prem resource that points to the NAT gateway.
- In subnet B, create a route for the IP CIDR of the on-prem resource that points to the VGW of the VPN connection.

Comment: How did this previously work for the EC2 instance in the same subnet (with a private IP from the same subnet CIDR, the same SG, and with the same routing)?